# How to copy custom Xorg.conf settings automatically on each boot

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, xorg, lxde, xserver

My issue is with an external graphics card that I sometimes use. When it is plugged in, LXDE changes the DPI settings and text/other items becomes unreadable.

The solution is copying this line into each of the "Screen" sections in "/etc/X11/xorg.conf""
`Option "DPI" "96 x 96"`

However, the issue is that when I disconnect/reconnect the external graphics card, the settings are reset to their defaults and I have to manually enter these settings again and reboot.

What I would like to do is make sure that my custom xorg.conf file is copied over early-on in the loading of the LXDE environment, this way the settings are permanently saved. (Or otherwise make the changes to xorg.conf permanent.)

Comment: Found Solution:

I needed to create this directory:
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

Then place a file called xorg.conf within containing the sections I am modifying, in my case the the file contained these settings to fix the DPI:

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
    Option "DPI" "96 x 96"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
    Option "DPI" "96 x 96"
EndSection

Answer (score 1):

Found Solution:

I needed to create this directory:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Then place a file called xorg.conf within containing the sections I am modifying, in my case the the file contained these settings to fix the DPI:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
    Option "DPI" "96 x 96"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
    Option "DPI" "96 x 96"
EndSection
```

Each time XServer is loaded, it will first generate the default Xorg.conf file, then it will load any changes from xorg.conf.d/*.conf files. Finally the service will start.

I was losing my settings made to xorg.conf because I had to place my modified xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/